# Is there a way to import json data and map each object to a separate doc in Firestore?

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a large JSON file, an array with lots of objects, I want to import these into firestore, and I want each object to become a document, and I am looking for the most efficient way to do it, any advice?

I have tried parsing and looping through some of the objects in the file and for each object run `let res = db.collection('mycoll').add(obj)`

This works, is there a smarter way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to import these into firestore, and I want each object to become a document

According to the official documentation, you can [import/export](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import) your data but only as long as you have one:

> You can use the Cloud Firestore managed export and import service to recover from accidental deletion of data and to export data for offline processing.

If you only have a JSON file, then you need to write some code for that.

> I have tried parsing and looping through some of the objects in the file and for each object run let res = db.collection('mycoll').add(obj)

That's the easiest way to do it. You can also add all the writes to a [batch](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) so it can be written atomically.

> This works, is there a smarter way to do it?

Once you have a database, use the import/export feature.